# Read keystore.properties from settings.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

*TL;DR: I want to store a key in `keystore.properties` and use it in `settings.gradle`.*

I have been following the [official advice](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) to use a `keystore.properties` file for my keys, and reading it from `build.gradle`, like so:

```
// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

Now the thing is that there is a key that I need in my `repositories { maven { ... } }` block, which happens to be in `settings.gradle` (seems like this is the new way).

But I can't run `def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")` from `settings.gradle` (my guess being that `rootProject` is not set at that point). I get the following error when I do:

> No signature of method: org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor.file() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [keystore.properties]

Is there a way to read a properties file from `settings.gradle`? I can write my key in `gradle.properties`, but that is not convenient since that file is versioned. Also using `-P` in the gradle invocation is not convenient with Android-Studio.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by doing the following:

```
def keystorePropertiesFile
for (file in getRootProject().getProjectDir().listFiles()) {
    if (file.name == "keystore.properties") {
        keystorePropertiesFile = file
    }
}
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

Though I wish I could make it cleaner.